# ignore text from input onfocus

Tags: javascript, css

I've a snag , here it is simple case

```
<input type="text" id="some" value="something">
```

and javascript

```
document.getElementById("some").onfocus = function(){
    this.style.opacity = 0.5;
};
```

It works just fine , but I want also that during this time (onfocus) mouse pointer be at the beginning of input field ( I mean to ignore default value , not to continue from "something") , any ideas ? thanks :))

P.S This is the just same like it is on facebook search, when focus search field and the default text become dim and the pointer moves at the beginning of input field

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this using the `onkeypress` event. Granted not the greatest piece of code, but it should get you started.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="some" value="something">
```

​
Javascript:

```
i = 1;
document.getElementById("some").onkeypress= function(){    
    if(i === 1) {
        document.getElementById("some").value = '';
        i = 0;
    }
    this.style.color = 'black';
}

document.getElementById("some").onfocus = function(){
    this.style.color = 'gray';
};
```

​
JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wZAvn/

Comment: this is really near to result , just seems to be need some changes , I'll try to figure it out , thanks anyways :))
It just want that onfocus pointer be at the beginning :)

Answer (score 0):

or something like this:

```
var some = document.getElementById("some"),
val = some.value; 
some.onfocus = function(){
    some.style.opacity = 0.5;
    some.value = (some.value == val )?"":some.value;        
};​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w5Kv8/1/

Comment: I do not meant to hide whole text onfocus , I just want onfocus that text would be dim and seen but the cursor pointer be at the beginning of text field